# Вот, я в беззаконии зачат, и во грехе... Вот – часть речи?

Tags: пунктуация, морфология

> **Вот,** я в беззаконии зачат, и во грехе родила меня мать. **Вот,** Ты возлюбил истину в сердце и внутрь меня явил мне мудрость [Твою].

Какой частью речи является слово "вот" в данных предложениях? Слово "вот" выделяется здесь по правилам русской пунктуации?

---

**текст из Синодального перевода*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вот, я в беззаконии зачат, и во грехе родила меня мать. Вот, Ты возлюбил истину в сердце и внутрь меня явил мне мудрость** [Твою].

***Вот*** ― указательная частица. Обычно частица не выделяется запятой, например:

**Вот я** и написал про них, а кто они такие ― не знаю. [Юрий Коваль. Про них (1988)]

**Но интонационное выделение возможно,** если, к примеру, идет указание на  сказанное ранее, например:

Вы ведь, птицы залётные, вроде ещё и не расписанные? **Вот, я так и догадывалась.** Ты в ночную смену, Данила? [Виктор Астафьев. Пролетный гусь (2000)]

**Чем объясняется пауза**:

Вот, (**как уже было сказано**)я в беззаконии зачат...

Но тот же текст может быть оформлен и без обособления ***вот***, если частицу  связать с текущим предложением.